# How to send a new line character "\n" through form tag in html

Tags: html, http, post, xss

I wanted to write a POC for XSS through POST method. After playing a lot with html form tags, I was finally able to construct a payload except for a single character "\n". XSS requires that character in order for it to work. Payload looks like this

`<input hidden=true type="search"  name="&#13;N<html><body><script>alert(document.domain)</script><h1>" value="</h1></body></html>">`

However a new line character `&#13;` after being submitted is converted to `\n\r` instead of `\n` in HTTP POST request. Is there any work around this problem ??

Comment: Why do you need the newline? Can you not just inject `">`?

Comment: It completely breaks if it doesn't accept that initial `\n` character, without adding `\n` it just gives an error with json payload instead of reflecting the payload. I think it is some kind of protobuf related stuff, although back end doesn't check for `content-type` header. That `N` after `&#13;` indicates the length of the payload in hexadecimal.

Comment: Originally `'\n'` moves the cursor only to the next line without moving the cursor back to column 0. `'\r'` is used for returning the cursor back to column 0. So using `"\n\r"` or `"\r\n"` is more correct than just using `'\n'`, especially in HTTP and similar protocols. Without `'\r'` your lovely teleprinter wouldn't work. You know, printing out HTTP pages via teleprinter is fun ;-) PS operating systems which automatically convert a `'\n'` to a `"\n\r"` do also automatically convert them back from `"\n\r"` to `'\n'` if needed so. `"\n\r"` is used by teleprinters, while `'\n'` is for displays.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is strange. Just putting an empty space before `&#13;` solves the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).